# Why isn't this creating the models in batch?

Tags: django, forms, post, django-models, size

I am trying to create the object blank in a batch but it is only creating one object after I fill in the form, could anyone help me with what I am doing wrong?

html

```
{% block content %}
    <form class="box" method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h1>Air Ticket Sales</h1>
        {{ form }}
        batch size:
        <input type="number" name="batch" value="{{ batch }}">
      <input type="submit" name="" value="Create Blank">

    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

model

```
class blank(models.Model):
    #an integer field that automatically increments by itself as the object are created
    number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=type_choices, default='green')
    is_sold = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_refunded = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    date.editable = True
    advisor = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

view

```
def create_blanks(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #initializes the data from the form to the value form
        form = blank_form(data=request.POST)
        batch = request.POST.get("batch", "")
        if form.is_valid():
            for b in batch:
                form.save()
            return render(request, "create_blanks.html")
        else:
            return render(request, "create_blanks.html")
    else:
        form = blank_form
        return render(request, "create_blanks.html", {'form':form})
```

Comment: Euh, you save the *same* form mltiple times...

Comment: shouldn't the AutoField automatically increment?

Comment: but the object is given a primary key, hence the second save will be an `UPDATE ...` query.

Comment: Is there anything else I can do to just save a new one?

Comment: Set the primary key to `None` again (so `form.instance.None`). But `for b in batch` looks strange as well. You likely want `for b in range(int(batch))` or something similar?

Comment: when I set the primary_key=none it just gives this Model blank_system.blank can't have more than one AutoField.

Comment: what's the code you use to set the pk to none?

Comment: number = models.AutoField(primary_key=None)

Answer (score 0):

Yep just found the solution with your help I don't think it is the most efficient or the cleanest one but here you go

```
for b in range(int(batch)):
            form.save()
            form.instance = None
            form = blank_form(data=request.POST)
```